# Finding where and why [object ErrorEvent] is being thrown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 1 test failing and the log is no help whatsoever, other than telling me which test it is that fails...

```
LoginComponent should display username & password error message and not call login when passed nothing FAILED
    [object ErrorEvent] thrown
    [object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

Is there any way I can trace the source of the error?

I have attempted to test with `ng test --source-map=false/true` but nothing seems to have changed.

I ran again with --watch to check if I could open the console on my Chrome window to get more information, to which it stated that `form.reset is not a function` so I commented this line out but I am still getting the same error in my log of `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` from the same test, however now the Chrome Karma window does not display the `form.reset` error, but just: `Uncaught Error: The requested path contains undefined segment at index 0`

Comment: did you try to get the two thrown error objects and looked into them? usually they should be of some help

Comment: That has been my trouble. Just getting [object ErrorEvent] in the IntelliJ console is literally useless to me! However after digging in the Karma console after applying `--watch` I do think that I have found a possible cause. It looks like the `this.returnUrl` is undefined and causing an issue for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Karma console did indeed print out a useful error: `Uncaught Error: The requested path contains undefined segment at index 0`.

I traced this back and it seems that the issue was with my routing to `this.returnUrl` and it being `undefined`. So I instantiated it in my declaration: `returnUrl: string = '';` and **BOOM**, no more error and the routing still works as intended.

I am not sure whether this is the correct fix, but it is a workaround for the time being.

Comment: Given your code and test, it is strange it works ... But good for you if it did ! (and it's not a workaround, it's a totally valid way of resolving the issue)

Comment: Now I just have to figure out why it doesn't think form.reset() or form.resetForm() are valid functions >:(

Comment: `emptyForm` doesn't implement them

Comment: Could you please clarify @trichetriche? I checked the log from the actual form against the 'fake' I send in, in the test and they are not of equal structure so I somewhat understand what you mean. But is there a way around this?

Comment: `const emptyForm = <NgForm>{ reset: () => null, resetForm: () => null, ... }`. Mock the functions inside your mock.

Comment: (if I recall correctly, I already explained to you you have to implement every object member you use in your component in your mock)

Comment: This hasn't worked for some reason :-/
I have opened a new question for this so we don't spam this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741701/angular2-typeerror-form-reset-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions :

- disable source mapping in your tests with the command `ng test --source-mapping=false`
- Open your browser's console, which will show you the real error.

Comment: Yeah that still just gave me the same output. I had trouble with keeping the Karma window open, so I had to use --watch. Could you have a look at the answer I just submitted and see if it makes sense?

Comment: in `karma.conf.js` you can set `autowatch: true` to automatically watch for changes. In fact, this is the default configuration ... I'm taking a look at your answer.