# Angular2+ - TypeError: form.reset is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

This is a question carried over from [Finding where and why [object ErrorEvent] is being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740922/finding-where-and-why-object-errorevent-is-being-thrown/51741146#51741146) as a result of troubleshooting a different problem.

I am mocking an NgForm to pass into my test for a login screen, however upon passing in incorrect details I am using `form.reset()` to reset the whole thing.

I get the error `TypeError: form.reset is not a function` in my Jasmine

I have been advised that my mock doesn't include any sort of reset function which does make a certain amount of sense, however amending the const to the following still does not help the test pass...

```
const emptyForm = <NgForm>{
    reset: () => null,
    resetForm: () => null,
    valid: false,
    value: {
      username: undefined,
      password: undefined,
    }
  };
```

Error log:

```
zone.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: form.resetForm is not a function
```

Comment: You're going to need to post the test in error and the related code too

Comment: Updated now @trichetriche

Comment: You don't get into your if statement and you implemented the mock correctly ... Are you sure your error is coming from there ?

Comment: Hmm. I see what you mean... I've added the console log from the Karma test screen.

Comment: I don't have access to pictures, could you post it as text ?

Comment: Updated now @trichetriche

Comment: Thank you ! I think your `onSubmit` function is triggered somewhere else in your component, such as `ngOnInit`, and it goes through your if statement. Could you check where `onSubmit` is called in your component ?

Comment: I have found the issue! Silly Karma was pointing to the wrong error. I have since moved `resetForm: () => null` to the mock form that **does** actually get to the reset function, and all is well. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: ... Sure, glad you resolved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Karma was sending the error from the wrong test, or at least misdirecting me from the actual cause of the error.

After I placed `resetForm: () => null` into the correct mock-form then all is well.